# SQL - Join tables based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I need to join the following 2 tables on column DBName:

Table A

```
ProductName DbName ServerName
A           DB1    sername
B           DB2    sername
C           DB3    sername
D           DB3    sername
```

Table B

```
ID DBName ObjectName
1  DB3    objC
2  DB2    objD
3  DB3    objD
4  DB1    objD
```

So that I can obtain a final table with following columns (i.e. all cols of Table B + Product Name) :

```
 ID DBName ObjectName ProductName
```

As you can see from Table A I have DB3 relating to 2 different ProductName (C and D) which results in a many to many relationship (i.e. if the col has DB3 after the join, it turns into 2 rows, one displaying C in ProductName and one is D.)

What I'd like to do is to get a 1-1 relationship by the conditions that if ObjectName is ObjD, then ProductName is D and if ObjectName is ObjC then ProductName is C.

Would be grateful if anyone could point me to the right way to go about this...

Thanks!!

Comment: Re: "if ObjectName is ObjD, then ProductName is D": Wouldn't that eliminate the rows with ID = 2 and ID = 4?

Comment: Where would I put that in the code though? Should be somewhere near the joins?

Comment: Why don't you post your desired output? That will help clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.ProductName
FROM    tableB a
        INNER JOIN tableA b
            ON  a.DBName = b.DbName  AND
                a.ObjectName LIKE '%' + b.ProductName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6162/2)

The query above works as expected but certainly have slow performance. It will perform `FULL TABLE SCAN` because it doesn't use and index.

Please do normalize your tables so search will use index.

Here's a suggested schema:

TableA

- ProductName
- DbName
- ServerName

TableB

- ID
- DBName
- ObjectName
- ProductName

and define a coumpundcolumn index on `ProductName, DbName` on both tables.

Comment: Thanks so much JW! I'll give it a go. I'm a SQL newbie - normalize the tables meaning creating indexes for each of them right?

Comment: The schema is what I currently have? Adding ProductName to TableB is exactly what I'm trying to achieve in this post!

Comment: @viv_acious not exactly creating indexes but building good database structure [see: Database Normalization Basics](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Answer (score 2):

That's ugly. (and can get slow). You should use integer ids for the join.

For your tables it would be:

```
SELECT b.ID, b.DBName, b.ObjectName, a.ProductName
FROM a
  JOIN b
    ON a.DBName = b.DBName
    AND CONCAT('%',a.ProductName) LIKE b.ObjectName
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks so much - I'll give it a go. What's integer ids?

Comment: Oh sorry. For SQL Server you seems to have to replace `CONCAT('%',a.ProductName)` with `'%' + a.ProductName`.